# Pessimistic locking mechanism with IReliableQueue in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I understand locking is scoped per transaction for IReliableQueue in Service Fabric. I have a requirement where once the data is read from the ReliableQueue within a transaction, I need to pass the data back to my client and preserve the lock on that data for a certain duration and if the processing fails in client, then write the data back to queue (preferably at the head so that it is picked first in next iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric doesn't support this. I recommend you look into using an external queuing mechanism for this. For example, [Azure Service Bus Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions) provides the functionality you describe.

You can use [this package](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus) to receive SB messages within your services.

Answer (score 0):

> preserve the lock on that data for a certain duration

We made that once or twice too in other contexts with success using modifiable-lists and a document-field LockedUntillUtc (initialized to mininimum or null, or using a different reliable collection of locked keys (sorted on LockedUntillUtc?) - which best suites your needs?).

If you can't trust your clients to adhere to such a lock-request and write/un-lock-request contract, consider an ETag pattern - only returned on a successfull lock-request...

Comment: Can you please elaborate or provide any links that give more details? You mean you achieved with Reliable collections in Service Fabric?